ASUS Vivobook S 15 S5504VA Fingerprint Device Not Detected
I have recently brought an ASUS Vivobook S15 S5504VA and I cannot get the fingerprint device to work or even be recognized by the OS. I have run 'fprint-enroll' and get the message "Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available".
I have also run 'lsusb' and I cannot see a device ID for the fingerprint sensor. I saw posts from a few years back about a lack of support for Asus Vivobooks, is this still the case? TIA.
Edit: It seems my fingerprint reader is a focaltech ft9349 ESS. Still cannot seem to find anything though unfortunately. According to Linux Hardware and Fprint it seems it isn't supported atm.

There was a question here in which the OP provided a link to a YouTube video which he indicated worked for him.

Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0. Also look at service fprintd status.
